# Flying on an Lufthansa ticket but can't get Miles & More points, what's going on?

Tags: lufthansa, miles-and-more

I bought a Premium Economy (class N) return ticket from Sydney to Frankfurt on the Lufthansa site. The last leg is a Lufthansa flight (LH9780) but the flight was operated by Singapore Airlines.

This last leg of the flight is not eligible for Miles & More points, even though the ticket is from Lufthansa and bought on the Lufthansa website.

Comment: Do you recall if the Lufthansa website told you that you get miles for the return flight before booking? If yes (and you happen to have a screenshot), you can try to contact the Miles&More people to try to get what you have been promised. Otherwise, you are likely to be out of luck. In the Star Alliance network, the milage credit is always based on what the program regulations for your bonus program tells about flying with the **operating airlines**, not the one booked with. This is different in other airline alliances, but when flying with Star Alliance, this is the case.

Comment: Did Luftansa tell you will not get miles or has it simply not shown up in your account yet?  Sometimes credit for code share flights shows up later, as it takes time for the operating carrier to tell the marketing carrier that yes Babybloomer boarded the flight out of Singapore.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I'm sure it buried somewhere in the fine print. I knew that if I was on a  Singapore Airlines ticket I was not going to get credit on Miles&More but foolishly assumed that since I had a Lufthansa ticket with a LH flight number I would get it.

Answer (score 9):

According to Lufthansa twitter, an LH N fare marketed by LH and operated by SQ maps to an SQ P fare class and earns 150%.

I couldn't find an up to date booking class alignment table for star alliance. There is an old one [here](https://portal.staralliance.com/stardesk/publications/reference_guide_2012.pdf) but it doesn't have premium economy on SQ. SQ has T, S and P premium economy fare classes and all earn 150% on M&M according to [wheretocredit](http://www.wheretocredit.com/singapore-airlines).

Comment: +1 this is the right information; as per Lufthansa and the comment from the OP on my deleted answer: _"Miles are allocated according to the operating carrier and seating class. As your Lufthansa flight from Singapore to Sydney from 27 July 2016 was actually operated by Singapore Airlines, your booked Lufthansa seating class N was amended to the corresponding Singapore Airlines tariff in P. Therefore, we have manually processed your missing flight with the correct flight number and seating class once more. As the data audit can take up to 25 days we ask you for more patience in this matter. "_